# How to print on Kyocero TASKalfa 356ci in color on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing, 22.04

Printing on a
Kyocero TASKalfa 356ci
from Ubuntu 20.04 worked after specifying an official .ppf file from
[here](https://dlc.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/service/dlc.false.driver.TASKALFA356CI._.EN.html).

However, printing from Ubuntu 22.04 using the same drivers results in
black and white printouts. The default color settings from the Ubuntu-Settings-Printer-Menu is black and white, but changing it to color does not change the printouts.

From within the Ubuntu-Settings-Color-Menu, I tried to assign color profiles to the printer, but having assigned color profiles did not change the printouts.

Comment: USB or network connected?

Comment: Network connected

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to a bug in CUPS:

https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/421

See also this report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1971242

A workaround suggested by a CUPS developer on GitHub is to issue the command:

lpadmin -p YOUR_PRINTER_NAME -o print-color-mode-default=color

Answer (score 0):

How about trying driverless printing? This should have been automatically given to you, but it can be done manually.

Execute `driverless` to get a **URI**. Now substitute what you get for URI in

`lpadmin -p 356ci -v "URI" -E -m everywhere`

and print to 356ci.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the printer is not showing up in the output of `driverless`.

Up to now, I addressed the printer by IP-address `172.22.XX.XXX`
I tried `lpadmin -p 365ci -v "socket://172.22.XX.XXX" -E -m everywhere`
but received `lpadmin: IPP Everywhere driver requires an IPP connection.`.

Comment: No output for `driverless`? There should be. I have double-checked and the device does AirPrint. How about `ippfind -T 5`? `everywhere`  must use a URI beginning `ipp://`.